# How can I import class from the same package in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package, java-package

How can I use one class from other class in the same package in the same directory? I have one class Utils:

```
package pl.jcubic;

public class Utils {
   public static String foo() {
      return "foo";
   }
}
```

and a class Service

```
package pl.jcubic;

public class Service {
   public String test() {
     return Utils.foo();
   }
}
```

both files have name the same as class, they are in directory `./pl/jcubic/` and when I compile Service I've got an error `error: cannot find symbol` in line where Utils is.

I've try

```
import Utils;
```

got 2 errors `error: '.' expected` and `error: ';' expected` in the same line

I've try

```
import pl.jcubic.Utils;
```

got `error: cannot find symbol` in line where import is and in the line where I use the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. I've compile using cd

```
cd pl/jcubic; javac  Service.java
```

but it don't work. But it work when I compile

```
$ javac pl/jcubic/Serive.java
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to (and cannot).

Classes in the current package are implicitly in scope.

If you get an error, make sure that the other class has been compiled.

Comment: It's compiled. I have Utils.class file.

Comment: @jcubic: Add `-cp .` to the compiler commandline to make it search the current directory.